# How to add two UITableViews to ViewController in storyboard?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

In my app, I want to handle 2 tables in one ViewController.
First I drag a UITableViewController into NavigationController, so there is already a UITableView.
Then I drag another UITableView to the scene, but the second UITableView can't be placed at the same level as first UITableView, it can only be a subview of first UITableView or replace the first UITableView. Here is the structs, please help.

[image]

Comment: Do you need any more help with your question?

Comment: In any `UIViewController` subclass you can only have one top-level view. In `UITableViewController` that's a `UITableView`, but in a "normal" view controller it's a generic `UIView`. Any other views you want are always going to be subviews of the top-level view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are using storyboards, your easiest option is to use container views. 
This will not allow you to put both tableviews into the same ViewController, but it is a very easy way to embed two other view controllers into one main view controller.

1. Get yourself a regular UIViewController
2. Drag two container views inside that view controllers view.
3. Add two tableviews to your storyboard.
4. Hold ctrl and drag from your container views to your newly created tableviews. Choose the `embed` segue.

*Now you can configure both table views individually in their own view controllers, but they will still be shown on the same screen.*

Comment: It's not allowed to add two container views inside a view controller, but can add two container views inside a view that the view is inside a view controller, is that right?

Comment: Well yes, that's what I meant. Of course you're right, that hierarchy wise, there is an additional view, that contains both of them. I changed my post accordingly. I was just referring to the view controller, since the view is automatically generated when you drag a new view controller into your storyboard.

Answer (score 11):

I think based on what you described, why not use UIViewController instead of UITableViewController and add a uiview first, and drag both of your table view into it.

[image]

Don't know what exactly you want to do, but in this case, the table delegate and datasource may need some extra if/else. But i think in any case, if you want to handle 2 table views in one view controller, the datasource and delegate needs extra attentions...

Comment: Using the same datasource for two different tableViews is not really a good idea (if they are supposed to show different content). In the case, that you are building a separate class to act as a delegate and data source for one of the tableviews, you might just as well give it its own view controller.